# Map a complex JSON string to a POJO class

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs

I want to map following JSON struct to a POJO class **automatically**:

```
{
    "fieldClass": 
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "b",
        "c": "c",
        "d": "d",
        "e": "e"
    }
}
```

I added the parameter to map JSON to POJO class to web.xml. Also I tried to define two class, one for wrapper class and one for inside class. But following exception is thrown when I tried to use some method:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/projectName] threw exception [org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fieldClass" (Class className), not marked as ignorable
>    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4d5d6704; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: className["fieldClass"])] with root cause

Can I map this to Java classes **automatically**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this section: [JSON.org Java section](http://www.json.org/java/)

Also Jackson [Quickstart guide](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Comment: "There is no way to do this automatically, you should parse the JSON string." this is what you mean, right?

Comment: Map the JSON string to a Java POJO

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example this is the mapping reference.

Comment: @Mikael - that link was very helpful!